# Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.taylortireauto.com/?s=contacts' was loaded over HTTPS

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to load the page. But I receive the error in console.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this error.

> ?s=contacts:1137 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.taylortireauto.com/?s=contacts' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure script
>   'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=init&key=AIzaSyAWqg9QTv27xihyKzZLnZf3wNKn0m7E62k'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

for more details please check below image.

[image]

Comment: Replace `http` with `https` in the `wp_enqueue_script()` URL for Google Maps or better leave it with no protocol specified: `//maps.google.com/........`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not able to find wp_enqueue_script() in my project. can you please tell me exactly where I need make changes??

Comment: Inspect the `functions.php` of your theme. Also, try to figure out what plugin is responsible for the map.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have enqueued google maps with `http://`

Go to your theme and find out where you enqueued google maps and change the URL `http` to `https`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. please tell me the exact location in theme. i can't find  where I need to make changes.

Comment: Search "maps" in your theme code, maybe you will find the map.
If you using third party plugin for maps deactivate the plugin.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I updated my theme and issue has been solved.